# Error: write EPROTO 4379422144:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332

Tags: react-native, expo

When i am running expo start with my project i am facing this error in the terminal.

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Opening exp://192.168.1.3:19000 on Pixel_4_API_30
Error: write EPROTO 4379422144:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)
```

expo-cli version = 4.3.2
node -v = v12.20.0 / v14.15.1

Comment: On a similar ssl error for `expo init` in my case, the solution was to properly set http_proxy and https_proxy. Try this if you are behind a proxy. Maybe expo tries to communicate with an external IP and fails.

Comment: @Gr3at how did u solve the problem, i am not making any api call and all, even expo login is giving the same error, and i have disabled all the proxy from the network. Still getting the same error.

Comment: So, just to clarify, i shall mention that i was behind a *company proxy*, which i couldn't bypass and my platform OS was *Windows 10*. Having said that, i wanted to ensure that `expo` would make request through the proxy (let's say http://companyproxy.com:8080).
So i edited [user environmental variables](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) and added two new entries. http_proxy=`http://companyproxy.com:8080` and https_proxy=`http://companyproxy.com:8080`.
That did the trick for me and allowed expo to communicate.